# how to get data from database to controller in grails 3

Tags: grails

i am new in grails 3 and i wanted to know that how we can get the values from the database to the controller
i tried

```
def std = Students.get(1)
```

but it returns only the id not the actual value

plzzzz can anyone help me

Comment: this is the way to load the student with the id=1.  i assume you some different problem then.  please provide the full problem (code, errors, ...)

Comment: what do you mean by actual value? after this line, try to print out his properties like `std.name` or some that you have. or just show more details. this part of your code is correct. give the full controller function and domain class for students. P.s. - usually domain names are written in singular.

Comment: i have a table in which the col are stdName and stdEmail now in stdName I have some value Harish Soni and in stdEmail someone.22@gmail.com now i want to get the value ie Harish Soni and someone.22@gmail.com how can i get the value and how can i store the value in a string format in any String variable..../???

Comment: smells like your `Student.toString()` returns only the `id`. This is what you see if you do `println std`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do:

```
def std = Students.findById(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing the result of get, the toString() default methods is call if you haven't create your own. Then if you do:

```
def std = Students.get(1)
println std
```

`Students: 1` will be printed

You can implement your toString() method as:

```
Students{
   String name
   String toString(){
      name
   }
}
```

In this case the result of println will be its name.
If you want to print all fields of the object just do

```
println std.dump()
```